# Unexpected nil found when wrapping an optional variable

Tags: swift

I keep getting this error and ive set conditions so that the bodyB is not nil when it is to be removed from its parent. However I still get this on going problem whilst running the app. I can wrap it using "?" instead but it duplicated the bodyB node (I recreate it after destroying it using the func createNewDart) Any ideas as why this is occuring

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BoardCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == DartCategory {
        counter++
        movement+=0
        board?.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(movement, 0))
        points.text = "Points: " + String(counter)
        if alive == true {
        contact.bodyB.node!.removeFromParent()
        alive = false
        }


    }

func createNewDart() {
    if alive == false {
    let dart = DartNode.dart(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 77))

    self.addChild(dart)
    alive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant exactly tell how to solve the problem but it is pretty easy to tell what is nil and shouldnt be by looking in the bottom part (just left of the error message) and browse through the variables and see which one = nil.  It may be your dart or board or something unrelated. Make sure the one that is nil is initialized ie ( var dart : SKNode!) and then defined ie ( dart.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(....) ) Hope this helps!